# count occurrences of strings from a text file in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, bufferedreader

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of days of the week in a textfile. As of right now my code counts the total number of occurrences but I need it to count the number of individual occurrences of each keyword. The output needs to look like this

```
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 0
```

etc.

Here's my code so far

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DayCounter
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{

    String[] theKeywords = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    // put each keyword in the map with value 0 
    Map<String, Integer> DayCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String str : theKeywords)
    {
        DayCount.put(str, 0);
    }

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Eclipse\\test.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        // read lines until reaching the end of the file
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {


            if (sCurrentLine.length() != 0) 
            {

                // extract the words from the current line in the file
                if (DayCount.containsKey(sCurrentLine))
                {
                    DayCount.put(sCurrentLine, DayCount.get(sCurrentLine) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {

        exception.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException exception) 
    {

        exception.printStackTrace();
    } 


    int count = 0;
    for (Integer i : DayCount.values()) 
    {
        count += i;
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nCount = " + count);
}
}
```

Comment: Whats not working at this point?

Comment: Its working but I can't figure out how to change the output to what I described in the question

Comment: Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: Looks good to me. What exactly is your current output?

Comment: My output is the total number of occurrences not the count of the individual key words

Comment: what is the output you get? What is your problem? Is there any exception? How the data in the text file are presented? Currently you are reading a line, not a word, in a line there might be number of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of just printing the sum :

```
for(String day : theKeywords) {
 System.out.println(day + " = " + DayCount.get(day));
}
```

Comment: Actually if I put the same string on a line it only counts it once(ex. Monday Monday)

Comment: @user2007843 then you need to split the strings, trim them and load into `HashMap`

Comment: sorry can you explain that a little more in depth?

Comment: @user2007843 So instead of checking for `if (DayCount.containsKey(sCurrentLine))`, use `split` on `sCurrentLine` which will give you `String[]`. Just iterate this array and check if any of these elements exist in DayCount`

Comment: is there a way to do this using indexof?

Comment: `indexOf` also could be used to identify the index of any of the string in `theKeywords` but the runtime complexity and the code to implement wont be clean while comparing with `split` and `search` which i ve explained before

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the sum of all the days.
Instead you want to print the value for each day.
So instead of

```
  for (Integer i : DayCount.values()) 
    {
        count += i;
    }
```

You should do

```
for(String Day: theKeywords) {
 System.out.println(Day+ " = " + DayCount.get(day));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (String crtDay : dayCount.keySet())
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %d", crtDay, dayCount.get(crtDay));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> count: DayCount.entrySet())
    System.out.println(count.getKey()+" = "+count.getValue());
```